# odoo creating custom backend form widget to render html view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

Hi i'm stuck on a widget creation that render a custom html content on a form view, I don't know how to follow. Here is my code

**js:**

```
(function (instance) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    console.log('hi..........');  // Custome message to dispaly on console
    openerp.my_module = function (instance, local) {
        console.log(instance);
        instance.web.form.widgets.add('my_module.home', 'instance.my_module.Home');
        instance.my_module.Home = instance.web.form.FormView.extend({
            template: 'my_template',
            init: function (view, code) {
                console.log("::: INIT");
            },
            start: function () {
                console.log("::: START");
            }
        });

    }
})(openerp);
```

**xml template**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-name="my_template">
            <div>
                Template content
            </div>
        </t>
    </templates>
```

At this point only show in the terminal the `'hi..........'` and the object instance, but never run the widget code. So my questions are. How to use it in the form configuration and if i´m missing something here

```
    <record id="view_form_my_module" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">My Module</field>
        <field name="model">my.module</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <sheet>
                    **HOW TO ISE IT HERE**
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: In version 15 not working.can you help for version15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you may really want to use a `FormWidget` rather than extending `FormView`. I am not an expert on javascript extensions. However if you follow the documentation for `The Form View Custom Widgets` found [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html#the-form-view-custom-widgets) you might find it easier to accomplish what you are going for. It is also easy to drop your widget in any form view, using the `<widget/>` tag.

```
local.YourWidgetClassName = instance.web.form.FormWidget.extend({
    start: function() {
        this._super();
        this.display_html();
    },
    display_html: function() {
        this.$el.html(QWeb.render("your_qweb_template", {
            "arg1": "Hello",
            "arg2": "World",
        }));
    }
});

instance.web.form.custom_widgets.add('widget_tag_name', 'instance.your_addon_name.YourWidgetClassName');
```

Now in you qweb I would call it like this.

```
<widget type="widget_tag_name"></widget>
```

Comment: when I use the < widget type="my_template" /> tag odoo trwos this error `web.assets_backend.js:3600 Uncaught TypeError: obj is not a constructor`

Comment: I wish I could be more helpful. I took what is in the documentation and pasted it in my answer and made some adjustments (as an example). Seems like it hates something about the definition of your `start` function. If this does not work I will provide a full working example later.

Comment: Try starting with a vanilla modified version of the FormWidget from the documentation. Once you have replaced their addon names and class names with something that makes sense for your addon. Then flesh it out with actual content. If your qweb says `<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>` and you can get that to appear on the screen then you can start moving forward.

Comment: I apologise if that is what you have been trying to accomplish. I spent the better part of a weekend the first time I tried creating a javascript extension. It is not an intuitive process.

Comment: Hello thanks for the help, but keep saying `Uncaught TypeError: obj is not a constructor` when i click on the form view

Comment: Ok, so you place some logging in your addon and you see it appear when you bring odoo up in your browser. So odoo is loading your js in the backend js files. Try replacing the widget type with something completely nonsense ( as a control ) . Also place some logging in your init or start function. If you get the exact same error and no logging to the console. Odoo cant find the widget with your tag name. Meaning it is likely not registered properly with the tag name you think it is.

Comment: Many thanks now Its working thanks!! only a letter mistake in your example miss the `e` on `local.YourWidgetClassNam`

Comment: Great, glad you are moving forward.

Comment: If anyone can tell me how to do this for odoo15? If I use this I am getting TypeError: Widget is undefined